# No me funciona la paginación de un DataGrid de ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

estoy tratando de hacer la paginación de 10 en 10 de un DataGrid que trae unos 50 registros de la base de datos, pero lo malo es que cuando le doy clic al botón siguiente para ver la siguiente página del DataGrid la página se recarga y se siguen mostrando los mismos datos de la primera página del DataGrid NO de la siguiente.

¿Alguno sabe como puedo corregir este problema?, De antemano Gracias.

Este es mi código de la página notas.aspx

```
<asp:DataGrid  ID="DataGrid1"  AllowPaging ="true" PageSize="10" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%"
   Height="50" DataKeyField="NOTE" GridLines="None" ForeColor="#333333">
   <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
   <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
   <Columns>
   <asp:BoundColumn DataField="DATE" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="DATE"
        Visible="true"></asp:BoundColumn>
   <asp:BoundColumn DataField="NAMEUSER" HeaderText="User" SortExpression="NAMEUSER"
        Visible="true"></asp:BoundColumn>
   <asp:BoundColumn DataField="NOTE" HeaderText="Note" SortExpression="NOTE"
        Visible="true"></asp:BoundColumn>
   <asp:BoundColumn DataField="AGENCY" HeaderText="Agency" SortExpression="AGENCY"
        Visible="true"></asp:BoundColumn>
   </Columns>
   <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
   <ItemStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
   <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
   <EditItemStyle BackColor="#999999" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479006.aspx#aspnet-pageablesortable_topic3), tienes que implementar el evento [PageIndexChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.pageindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) para así obtener la página seleccionada y rebindear la grilla:

```
Sub Grid_Change(sender As Object, e As DataGridPageChangedEventArgs) 
    DataGrid1.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    DataGrid1.DataSource = CreateDataSource()
    DataGrid1.DataBind()
End Sub
```